# Can I copy my objects to another scene?

Tags: scene

In my game every level is a different scene and i want my character to be in all of them. Also is there a way to make changes that only affect my character in a particular scene?

Answer (score 0):

You can make as many copies of your character than you need by selecting it and using Shift+D repeatedly. The copies will not be linked, thus you can modify each one in any way you want without affecting the others.